# How to change working directory in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012

How can I change the working director of Visual Studio C++ 2012. The default working directory is `$(ProjectDir)`, every file I create in my codes are created in the project directory. What I want is that every file is created in the source code's directory, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no convenient way to do it, but there are some workarounds.

- One solution is to move project file to `source` directory.
- Another solution is to add whole `source` directory to project (just drag'n'drop directory from windows explorer to project in solution explorer). Now, you can add items by right-clicking at `source` directory in solution explorer. They'll go to physical `source` folder. This surely works on Visual Studio 2013 RC, but I'm not quite sure about Visual Studio 2012.
- One more solution, is to create [Project Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247121.aspx) or even [Plugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/esk3eey8.aspx). It's along story. Maybe, someone already done this, but I was unable to find.